# invalid json error while upload base64 encoded image from browser to nodejs, express

Tags: node.js, file-upload, base64

I'm using express 4.13.1
my http request is as below

[image]

I get below error from node

[image]

but i have not configured a parser for the route

> /api/uploader/upload_profile_image_base64/

my controller code is as below to process the base64 encoded image, the request is failing before reaching the controller method

```
exports.handleProfileImageUploadBase64 = (req, res) => {
  console.log('>>>gg',req.body,'gg<<<');
  let matches = req.body.match(/^data:([A-Za-z-+\/]+);base64,(.+)$/);

  if (matches.length !== 3) {
    return res.status(400).send('Unexpected request body');
  }

  let type = matches[1];
  let imageBuffer = new Buffer(matches[2], 'base64');
  console.log('>>>uu',imageBuffer,'uu<<<');
  let imgPath = path.resolve('./profile_image_uploads/');
  fs.writeFile('test.jpg', imageBuffer.data, function(err) {
    console.log('>>>gg',err,'gg<<<');
  });
  fs.readdir(imgPath, (err, files) => {
    files.forEach(file => {
      console.log('>>>pp',file,'pp<<<');
    });
  });
  res.json({
    "img":type
  });
  /*res.end();*/
};
```

here is my route definition in uploader.js

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
const uploadController = require('../../app/controllers/upload_controller');

router.route('/upload_profile_image_base64')
  .post(uploadController.handleProfileImageUploadBase64);
```

and app.js as below

```
const express = require('express');
const uploader = require('./config/routes/uploader');
const cors = require('cors');
const app = express();

const corsOptions = {
  origin: 'http://localhost:4200',
  optionsSuccessStatus: 200, // some legacy browsers (IE11, various SmartTVs) choke on 204
  methods: 'GET,HEAD,PUT,OPTIONS,POST,DELETE',
  credentials: true
};
app.use(cors(corsOptions));
app.use('/api/uploader', uploader);
```

Comment: change the response to res.json({ img: type });

Comment: actually the request does not even hit the controller method, the exception stack trace on node is when request sent from the browser, i suppose invalid json given due to base64 image in http body is not valid json and i don't want it to be parsed by a json parser which is body-parser middle ware, even though i have not configured it for this route express seem to parse it anyway

Comment: If you don't want to use json parser then why are you setting header type of your request as "Application/Json"? Why not send as "form-data" or as "x-www-form-urlencoded"?